# Overriding API response

Tags: strapi

Is there a way to override the API response of a model ?

I have a /products routes, returning an array of products :

```
[{id: 1, name: "product1"}, {id: 2, name: "product2"}]
```

I want to add an attribute to the response like :

```
[{id: 1, name: "product1", foo: "foo"}, {id: 2, name: "product2", foo: "foo"}]
```

This foo attribute will be a value that I will fetch on an other model.

**Remark : the field is a calculated field**

I tried on the model to do something like that :

```
beforeFetchAll: async (model, columns, options) => {

    model.foo = 'foo';
},
```

But it's not seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

**beforeFetchAll** has in callback only model argument
`beforeFetchAll: async (model) => {},`

I suggest you define new attribute in the `product.settings.json` and update every entity in the **afterCreate** lifecycle alback

```
afterCreate: async (model, result) => {
    model.set('foo', 'foo');
  },
```

Comment: thank you for answer ! but i need to get this field when I fetch the product (like a calculated field)

Comment: Maybe you can try combine with REST API
```POST /content-manager/explorer/:model``` and ```POST 
/products```